# How to assign textfile string to dictionary value into one variable and how to extract the value by passing key in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I am reading a text file from the local file system. I want to convert String to Dictionary(MAP) store it into one variable. And want to extract value by passing key. I am new to spark scala.

```
  scala>val file = sc.textFile("file:///test/prod_details.txt");

  scala> file.foreach(println)

  {"00000006-0000-0000": "AWS", "00000009-0000-0000": "JIRA", "00000010-0000-0000-0000": "BigData", "00000011-0000-0000-0000": "CVS"}

  scala> val rowRDD=file.map(_.split(","))
```

Expected Result is :

If I pass the key as "00000010-0000-0000-0000",

the function should return the value as BigData

Comment: what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Spark 2.3 version

Comment: what's the file size ?

Comment: size is 100 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is in json format and is not big you can read your file with spark json connector and then extract keys and columns :

```
 val df = session.read.json("path to file")
 val keys = df.columns
 val values = df.collect().last.toSeq
 val map = keys.zip(values).toMap
```

Comment: sorry I forget to tell one thing.            outputDf= outputDf.withColumn("Value", getProductValuebyPassingId(outputDf.col("Key"))) . getProductValuebyPassingId method having all the above code. Passing Key column , and getting the value from the json file.